# How to translate a Valloy virtual function code into an Alloy script?

Tags: alloy

I am working on a project and found out an article about Valloy they give an example of a code both in Valloy and Alloy but the problem is that the syntax of the Alloy script is not recognised by the Alloy analyser.
Exp :

```
fun Object::equals(obj: Object) {
this.class = Object_Class => this..Object_equals(obj)
this.class = Dimension_Class => this..Dimension_equals(obj)
this.class = Dimension3D_Class =>this..Dimension3D_equals(obj) }
```

the analyser can't accept a function with no return type and does not know the ".." !!
can any one help with this ?!!

Thank u in advance !!

Comment: you might want to contact the authors of the article directly. I doubt anybody but them can help you with this problem.

Comment: @LoïcGammaitoni thank u for ur comment !! I did in fact but they said it've been too long since they wrote it so they could't help !! my prob is that I need to find the equivalent of the ".." in Alloy's current version

Comment: Isn't this some "Valloy"-specific syntax?

Comment: @BernardoFerreiraBastosBraga well that's what i figured out eventually even though in the article : http://users.ece.utexas.edu/~khurshid/testera/valloy.pdf  It was given as the Alloy translation of a Valloy code !! that's what massed up with my comprehension

Answer (score 0):

That syntax is not standard Alloy.  I'm not sure if VAlloy is still maintained or whether you can get it from the authors of that paper.

Comment: I have decided to translate it to the Alloy syntax that works for me, but I won't lie I'm still struggelling big time with it !!